# How many hours of SMART power on hours use should a new hard drive have?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

Purchased a new HGST hard drive. Using smartctl on OS X the new drive shows 71 hours of power on hours

Does this make sense or is this a sign of a refurbished drive?  I can't imagine why the manufacturer would need it powered on for almost 3 days.  I can confirm these values are not minutes or seconds (they have not changed)

```
Model Family:     Hitachi Ultrastar 7K4000
Device Model:     Hitachi HUS724020ALE640
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       71
```

Comment: I am not sure how Hitachi ships their drives, but at least Western Digital I know for a fact that when you buy a new drive it has 0 power on hours.

Comment: @Cha0s Not really. I've bought several new WD drives with a few dozen hours on them.

Comment: A refurbished drive will have the SMART data wiped. You'll see ~0 power on hours on both new and refurbished drives. A quick thought, it may be a returned product, but it's just my guess, no evidence.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am just lucky then. I've *never* bought a new WD drive with power on hours other than zero (I always check that and I've bought quite a few WD drives over the years). It may just be what msg7086 mentioned where they would wipe the SMART data prior to shipping or most likely a returned product with a few power on hours?

Comment: Last i bought a new one HGST drive - HDN724030ALE640 3TB.
When i put it ino my machine - it had 5 or 6 Power_On_Hours in SMART.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may see a number of power-on hours on a new drive. It is normal for drive manufacturers to test their drives prior to shipping.

For instance, [WD RE drives are burn-in tested](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=580):

> Each drive is put through extended burn-in testing with thermal cycling to ensure reliable operation.

Hitachi is less specific about [your particular drive](http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/enterprise-sata-drives/ultrastar-7k4000), though they do say:

> Engineered for the highest quality, the Ultrastar 7K4000 is put through grueling design tests during development and must pass stringent ongoing reliability testing during manufacturing.

Answer (score 0):

IMO anything over 10 is used. The last time I ran an extended "long"
SMART Test around 3hrs. This does vary and a big difference from "short test".
I bought a Seagate external portable 5TB from Amazon. I thought perhaps it was testing. Only if it was a small number of hours. In my case the drive has 1026 Hours powered on equals 42.x days. I only got the drive minus 8Hrs for a "Full" format. I decided to inspect after format. Usually any errors or bad spots show up during a full format.